# Complaint from openni_launch on already advertised services

Tags: kinect, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> [ERROR] [1323213598.693718118]: Tried
> to advertise a service that is already
> advertised in this node
> [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
> [ERROR] [1323213598.725968778]: Tried
> to advertise a service that is already
> advertised in this node
> [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]

This appears after the processes have started up when I run.

> roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12244/complaint-from-openni_launch-on-already-advertised-services/) by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-12-06**:
Maybe a previous run had not shut down completely? Was roscore still running from before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are not doing anything wrong. This is a bug with plugins to image_transport - under the right conditions their dynamic_reconfigure services can collide, producing those errors. It's ticketed at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4883 .

The error output is annoying but in practice doesn't cause much harm, so this has been a low-priority item.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-12-06**:
Appreciated.

**Comment by [freadx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4069/freadx/) on 2013-03-17**:
So, If i download the path will that error go away?

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2014-01-28**:
As suggested I ignored the error for the time being, But unable to see the image in RVIZ using Image panel. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, I found out how to get rid of that annoying error message. The reason for that error is that really **roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch** is trying to publish twice some of the topics.

I am using ROS Electric, but I think the following also applies to Fuerte:

Taking a look at the file **openni.launch** one can see that, among other things, it includes another launch file

```
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/includes/device.launch">
```

Then, the file **device.launch** includes (very elegantly) some other launch files

```
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/includes/rgb.launch" ns="$(arg rgb)">
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/includes/ir.launch" ns="$(arg rgb)">
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/includes/depth.launch" ns="$(arg rgb)">
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/includes/depth_registered.launch" ns="$(arg rgb)">
...
```

The problem is that the launch file **depth_registered.launch** includes **again** the launch file **depth.launch**, but this time with a flag to disable the generation of the point_xyz generation. I don't know why it is doing it, I see no reason for it considering that **depth.launch** is already running.

So, a workaround to the error of this post is to comment out the following from the **depth_registered.launch** file

```
<!-- Get all the usual depth topics -->
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/includes/depth.launch"
   ns="$(arg depth_registered)">
    <arg name="manager"    value="$(arg manager)" />
    <arg name="points_xyz" value="false" /> 
    <arg name="bond" value="$(arg bond)" />
</include>
```

If you comment those lines, the error goes away and everything seems to work just fine.

I hope this could be helpful for you too.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harsha](https://answers.ros.org/users/3217/harsha/) on 2012-09-21**:
Thanks for helping get rid of the annoying error messages.